# Wordpress - add %lang% to the beginning of every url/permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

I need a little guidance on how to accomplish this task I have been looking into over this past week. I have a feeling this has been solved somewhere but after searching all week I can't find it.

I am building a site which is using custom post types as well as pages and regular categories with posts. I have integrated google translate into the site and this works fine with my custom flags using the jQuery on click event and loading the selected language when you visit the site.

However I need to add the 2 character lang code to the beginning of my urls, for example:-

```
domain.com/fr/page,
domain.com/fr/category,
domain.com/fr/category/postname,
domain.com/fr/custom_post_type
```

This is my permalinks structure - /%lang%/%category%/%postname%/

I have this in my functions file, hence the %lang% in my permalinks structure.

```
function add_lang_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%lang%', '([a-z]{2})');
}
add_action('init', 'add_lang_tag', 10, 0);
```

It works for the regular categories and posts but it does not work for pages, search or custom post types.

For reference this question came seriously close to sloving my problem - [Wordpress add_rewrite_tag(), add_rewrite_rule(), and post_link()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754505/wordpress-add-rewrite-tag-add-rewrite-rule-and-post-link) - The main issue with this solution is that it did not work for regular pages.

I have also tried pretty much all of the multilingual plugins available for wordpress and none of them match my seemingly simple requirements, if I can acheive this pruely through add_rewrite_tag and cvhanging the peralinks I think there might be a few others who could benefit from it.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too late, but still I am giving this for user's who are still looking for this solution ---

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_page_rules' );

function custom_page_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . '/%lang%/%pagename%'; 
}
```